# GROUP BY select within SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have one table which i want to select some rows and group them by date. the problem is `when i'm selecting within my select that row appear to not grouped by date`, see the example:

```
SELECT date, SUM(price), (SELECT SUM(price), date FROM expense WHERE 
user = 'Catherine') as cprice FROM expense GROUP BY date
```

it does not grouping `cprice`, it will sum all Catherine prices and doesn't group it by date, by the way I tried GROUP BY date into the within select but doesn't work either.Any suggestion?

```
expense table:
id   user      price   date
1    Frank      20     2014
2    Catherine  10     2013
3    Catherine  20     2014
```

thank you

Comment: can you show some sample data?

Comment: i doubt that this statement will even work? returning two colmns in sub query

Comment: could you plass descrobe What you are trinn to achive with the subselect.

Comment: it would be more easier to explain if you can show your desired inan tabular form

Comment: @Skywalker i want the query select all prices sum and Catherine prices sum not separate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  SUM(price) as totalPrice, 
  SUM(IF(user='Catherine', price, 0)) as cprice 
FROM expense 
GROUP BY date
```

If you want both price together then you can try this:

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  SUM(price) + SUM(IF(user='Catherine', price, 0)) as cprice
FROM expense 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: First one works well, didn't try second one, Thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

try this query, it select * row where user = 'Catherine' and  groups them by date

```
SELECT 
     date,
     SUM(price)
FROM expense
WHERE user = 'Catherine'
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: i know, i want the query select all prices sum and Catherine prices sum not separate

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `Case Statement`:(*I'm Not Familiar With MySQL :(* )

Not Sure,Like:

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  SUM(price) as totalPrice, 
  SUM(Case When user='Catherine' Then price Else 0 End CASE;) as catherine_price 
FROM expense 
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

You probaby can solve it using a two selects and pull out the data you need using a loop.